# How to disable CIFS Null Login sessions

Tags: server, permissions, mount, samba, cifs

I scanned my servers on vulnerabilities recently and some ubuntu servers have following issue: **CIFS NULL Session Permitted**

Description:
*NULL sessions allow anonymous users to establish unauthenticated CIFS sessions with Windows or third-party CIFS implementations such as http://www.samba.org or the http://www.opensolaris.org/os/project/cifs-server/ . These anonymous users may be able to enumerate local users, groups, servers, shares, domains, domain policies, and may be able to access various MSRPC services through RPC function calls.  These services have been historically affected by numerous vulnerabilities.*

Which settings do I need to set in my smb.conf file to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In smb.conf, this is what I did:

I added / changed these lines to

```
map to guest = Never # Disables any login with a non-user
 restrict anonymous = 2 # Disables recon potential 
usershare allow guests = no # Not sure exactly what this does, but looked like a good one to set to no
```

Then, I also changed any guest_ok lines to no

```
guest ok = no
```

Comment: Oh right, haha, then do `service smbd restart`   Then, the vulnerability scanner did not detect the issue anymore. Another way to manually test is to use the net command from windows to try and do a null session. As far as I can tell, the scanner is looking to see if it can do that or login. https://www.dummies.com/programming/networking/null-session-attacks-and-how-to-avoid-them/